# How to pass array list to alert dialog's method builder.setItems

Tags: android

Is there any way to pass arrayList to alertDialog method `builder.setItems` because it is accepting string array

```
public void getMember() {
    ArrayList<String> MemberList = new ArrayList<>();
    MemberList.add("tahir");
    MemberList.add("usman");
    MemberList.add("waqas");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManagerHome.this);
    builder.setTitle("Member List");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp);

    builder.setItems(MemberList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your `MemberList` to array and then pass it to `setItems` method. just like below:

```
public void getMember() {
    ArrayList<String> MemberList = new ArrayList<>();
    MemberList.add("tahir");
    MemberList.add("usman");
    MemberList.add("waqas");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManagerHome.this);
    builder.setTitle("Member List");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp);

    builder.setItems(MemberList.toArray(new String[0]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: after converting the array list into string array, data of the array list is not showing on the alert dialog.empty alert dialog is showing.

Comment: @AbbasAli, I test this code myself and it works fine, except I haven't the `R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp` resource and use another icon. but the main solution this is not affected by it. I update my answer with an image from my output, if your code not working, maybe it has another problem, share what you have tried and update your question

Comment: @AbbasAli, please don't forget to mark as accepted answer if you find this answer  (or any other answer in your future questions) usable for you. for more information about accepting an answer you can read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) happy coding :)

Comment: you completely changed the question content!!! this is not correct, you must ask a new one if your problem completely different than the present question and update it when adding a relevant content helps others to understand your problem better. please undo your question to previous version and ask a new one.

Comment: If your information does not appear in the list, there is a problem with fetching data from Firebys and it's not about Dialer. Default data is not fetched at all, and therefore there is nothing to display on the list